# c++ Pointer of pointer gives a value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am wondering one thing, I am trying to remember c++ after long working with c# :)
And one thing bugs me, and I don't know why it is happening.
Pointer should be thing, which points somewhere to memory(it's address)
And pointer of pointer is address of the pointer. Simple, right? :D

Let's take a look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* TestMas = new int[10]
    {
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", *(TestMas+i));
    }
}
```

For some reason, values are printed out instead of the addresses, it should be *(TestMas+i) should be address of the array pointer, but how values are printed out, and not address?
If I try to use `&` to dereference the pointer, I get an error xD How is it working?

Comment: There is no pointer-to-pointer action going on. Just one level of indirection, so as soon as you dereference, you're right at the value. `*(TestMas+i)` is the same as `TestMas[i]`.

Comment: But at definition of array I use int* not just int. And at the print it should be something like int**

Comment: `int* TestMas` is a pointer to an `int`. Just one level of indirection. It can only hold one level. `int** TestMas` would be a pointer to a pointer. `new int[10]` provides a pointer to the first element of the array, not  pointer to an array. All a pointer can ever know is the first of potentially many. This is why you cannot determine the size of an array from the pointer.

Comment: Side note: When you want to print a pointer, use`%p`, not `%d`. `%d` prints an integer, and an integer isn't a pointer. This would invoke [Undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you had a pointer. One outcome of the UB is the pointer could be a different size and you wind up printing garbage.

Comment: You are confusing operators and their meaning in different contexts (I don't blame you, it's a mess and you have to get used to it). `*` near a variable declaration creates a pointer variable, but after declaration it means "dereference". `&` near variable declaration make a reference variable, but after declaration it means "address of". And then both have also arithmetic meanings...

Answer (score 2):

`TestMas` is a `int *`, or the address of an integer. When you assign it to `new int[10]`, you're pointing it to the first of 10 *contiguous* integers in memory that you guarantee belong to you.

So when you do `*(TestMas + i)`, you're doing pointer arithmetic, and then dereferencing the new pointer. Note that the syntactic sugar for exactly this operation would be `TestMas[i]`.

You probably meant to leave off the dereference if you just wanted the address. So just:

```
std::cout << TestMas + i;
```

Comment: Unrelated: You can't do this with a pointer to`char`. Almost always when a `char *` is passed to `<<`, the program wants to print a null-terminated string, so `<<` will try to print a string rather than the address. Cast the `char*` to `void *` and you can print the address.

Answer (score 2):

`TestMas` is a pointer to an `int`, not a pointer to a pointer. Its type is `int *`. A pointer to a pointer to an int would be `int **`

`TestMas + i` is also a pointer to an `int`, pointing to the i-th element of the array. `*(TestMas + i)` is calling the [indirection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) operator on that pointer, which returns the object or function pointed-to by the pointer operand, not the address.

The address is the value of `(TestMas+i)` itself.

You can print it with:

`printf("%p\t", (TestMas+i) );`